# Connect TV to mobile via HDMI port

Tags: hdmi

I have LG TV which has a HDMI port only. How to connect my mobile Micromax Nitro 311 via HDMI port?

Comment: I think your device does not support MHL Out. Check this first. Anyway, you can try to use an adapter (I use an micro-USB to HDMI for my device).

Answer (score 0):

If your mobile can support HDMI, you can buy an [USB MHL to HDMI](http://www.amazon.fr/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=USB%20MHL%20to%20HDMI&rh=n%3A13921051%2Ck%3AUSB%20MHL%20to%20HDMI), or [SlimPort to HDMI](http://www.amazon.fr/Adaptateur-SlimPort-HDMI-Nexus-Optimus/dp/B00O07TZJQ%3Fpsc%3D1%26SubscriptionId%3DAKIAJ2BX7QG7HCSMLDQA%26tag%3Dlmdn-api-21%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB00O07TZJQ).

The last option is to try the Google [Miracast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast) which allows you ton display 1080p content wirelessly.